# Flutter bug with RawAutocomplete

Tags: flutter

Hi im working with a RawAutocomplete widget to create a textfield that could show suggestions, everything is working fine until the list of suggestions is more bigger than 200 elements, one the list is that big and type faster in the keyboard the app start a loop searching for suggestions and never ends, i wanna now if there is a way to solve it.
The debug console show me this:

```
I/TextInputPlugin(25239): Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25239): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25239): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25239): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25239): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

and here is my code:

```
class AutoComplateTextTest extends StatelessWidget {
  bool readOnly;
  List<String> optionsLabel;
  TextEditingValue initialValue;
  BuildContext context;
  dynamic objeto;
  String label;
  Function onSelectedObj;
  Function clearObj;
  Widget? iconInfo;
  Widget? newBeneficiario;
  bool showSpace;
  bool row;
  bool showBotones;
  Locale? localeSaved;
  AutoComplateTextTest(
      {required this.readOnly,
      required this.optionsLabel,
      required this.initialValue,
      required this.context,
      required this.objeto,
      required this.label,
      required this.onSelectedObj,
      required this.clearObj,
      this.iconInfo,
      this.newBeneficiario,
      this.showSpace = true,
      this.showBotones = true,
      this.localeSaved,
      this.row = false});

  Widget _textField(BuildContext context, TextEditingController controller,
      FocusNode focus, Function onSelected) {
    double viewInsets = EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(
            WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets,
            WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio)
        .bottom;
    double espacioY;
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) {
      espacioY = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 400;
    } else {
      espacioY = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) / 400;
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: RawAutocomplete<String>(
                  initialValue: initialValue,
                  optionsViewBuilder: _optionsViewBuilder,
                  fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, focusNode, onSelect) {
                    return TextFormField(
                      style: TextStyle(height: espacioY),
                      readOnly: readOnly,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      controller: controller,
                      focusNode: focusNode,
                      inputFormatters: [UpperCaseTextFormatter()],
                      onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                        onSelect;
                      },
                      decoration: StyleTextFormField().decoration(label,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          colorText: Colors.black,
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                          suffix: showBotones
                              ? objeto == null
                                  ? IconButton(
                                      icon: const Icon(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        Icons.expand_more_outlined,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        focusNode.requestFocus();
                                      })
                                  : optionsLabel.length > 1
                                      ? IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            Misc.iconoBorrar,
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            ReqBusyState stateReq =
                                                BlocProvider.of<ReqBusyBloc>(
                                                        context)
                                                    .state;
                                            if (stateReq is ReqBusyInitial ||
                                                stateReq is ReqBusyFalseState) {
                                              clearObj(context);
                                              controller.text = "";
                                            }
                                          })
                                      : null
                              : null),
                    );
                  },
                  optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                    if (readOnly) {
                      return [];
                    }
                    return optionsLabel.where((String option) {
                      return removeDiacritics(option).toLowerCase().contains(
                          removeDiacritics(textEditingValue.text)
                              .toLowerCase());
                    });
                  }),
            ),
            iconInfo ?? Container()
          ],
        ),
        showSpace
            ? Misc.space(h: viewInsets <= 0.0 || readOnly ? 0.0 : viewInsets)
            : Container(),
      ],
    );
  }

 
  Widget _optionsViewBuilder(context, onSelected, options) {
    double espacioY = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 5;
    double espacioX;
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) {
      espacioX = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) / 1.2;
    } else {
      espacioX = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width) / 1.2;
    }

    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.black,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50.0))),
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: espacioY,
          width: row ? espacioX / 2 : espacioX,
          child: _listViwer(context, options, onSelected, espacioY),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _listViwer(context, options, onSelected, espacioY) {
    ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
    return options.length > 2
        ? FlexibleScrollbar(
            alwaysVisible: true,
            controller: controller,
            scrollThumbBuilder: (ScrollbarInfo info) {
              return AnimatedContainer(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 80.0),
                width: info.isDragging ? 5 : 10,
                height: info.thumbMainAxisSize,
                color: Colors.grey,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              );
            },
            child: Column(
              children: [
                newBeneficiario ?? Container(),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: controller,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    itemCount: options.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final String option = options.elementAt(index);
                      return _onTap(context, option, onSelected, espacioY);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        : Column(
            children: [
              newBeneficiario ?? Container(),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  itemCount: options.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final String option = options.elementAt(index);
                    return _onTap(context, option, onSelected, espacioY);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
  }

  Widget _onTap(context, option, onSelected, espacioY) {
    S textos = S.of(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: espacioY * 0.33,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            if (label == textos.titulo_info_buque) {
              await onSelectedObj(option, context, funcion: onSelected);
            } else if (label == textos.label_commoditys) {
              await onSelectedObj(option, context, localeSaved: localeSaved);
              onSelected(option);
            } else {
              await onSelectedObj(option, context);
              onSelected(option);
            }
          },
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(
              option.toString().toUpperCase(),
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController controllerText = TextEditingController();
    FocusNode focust = FocusNode();
    return _textField(context, controllerText, focust, onSelectedObj);
  }
}
```

I've tried change the total of elements, change the type of keyboard and change the builder to other widgets to test